# Table to point/raster in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to visualize the following table in google Earth Engine:

[image]
What I need is either:

1. Visualize it as a point feature, drawing the value 'tipEst_2012' with different colors. Radius value around 180 m.
2. Export it to a raster with raster value = tipEstiu_2012 and pixel size=180 m.

I've been looking for scripts to do so but I couldn't find any. You can find my data here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/oriolbaena/tipestiu

My script so far is:

```
var tipestiupoints=ee.FeatureCollection("users/oriolbaena/tipestiu");
var tipestiuraster = tipestiupoints
  .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['tip_Est2012']))
  .reduceToImage({
    properties: ['tip_Est2012'],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
});

Map.addLayer(tipestiuraster,{},'tipestiu')
```

Comment: We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your feature collection is malformed. It does not have a geometry and has fields that are combined into one field named **pointid;x;y;tipEst_2012**. It would be a good idea to clean it and and upload a proper shapefile. It might also be better to add a new field or convert the **tip_Est2012** to a numeric field representing classes so that the rasterization works without an issue

Comment: Thanks Nishanta for your answer! The point is that I don't have a proper shapefile, just a table with x and y (I know the Coordinate system of it). I would normally use _'Table to point'_ tool in ArcMap, but I would like to skip that step and just go from a **table with  coordinates** to a **raster**, and do it in Google Earth Engine. Thanks again!

Comment: It seems like you have a CSV file that is semi colon delimited. I think you need to at least convert it to comma delimited. If you want to use the file that is already uploaded, you can parse the combined column into different columns. you can see that here https://code.earthengine.google.com/5af0e1a8b1f9ef1bc21447af0b0fe546. You'll probably need to change the projection system as i think the one I have used here is wrong. Also, I think you might run into some computation issues as you have too many points.